# Kubernetes Volume Binding results in stale data

Tags: kubernetes

My Kubernetes Deployment is composed like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Values.web.service.name }}"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.namespace }}"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: "{{ .Values.web.deployment.selector }}"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: "{{ .Values.web.deployment.selector }}"
    spec:
      {{- if $.Values.vault.serviceAccount }}
      serviceAccountName: "{{ $.Release.Name }}-vault-auth"
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      {{- end }}
      volumes:
        - name: shared-data
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: vault-token
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
        - name: company-config
          configMap:
            name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-config"
            items:
              - key: companyRootCA.crt
                path: companyRootCA.crt
        - name: vault-consul-config
          configMap:
            name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-vault-configmap"
            items:
              - key: vault_agent.hcl
                path: vault_agent.hcl
              - key: consul_template_config.hcl
                path: consul_template_config.hcl
              - key: config.tmpl
                path: config.tmpl
      containers:
        - name: vault-agent-auth
          image: vault
          volumeMounts:
            - name: company-config
              mountPath: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/companyRootCA.crt
              subPath: companyRootCA.crt
            - name: vault-consul-config
              mountPath: /etc/vault/vault_agent.hcl
              subPath: vault_agent.hcl
            - name: vault-token
              mountPath: /home/vault/
          env:
            - name: VAULT_ADDR
              value: "{{ .Values.vault.endpoint }}"
            - name: VAULT_NAMESPACE
              value: "company/devops/tarchon/{{ .Values.environmentName }}"
          args:
            [
              "agent",
              "-config=/etc/vault/vault_agent.hcl",
              "-log-level=debug"
            ]
        - name: consul-template
          image: hashicorp/consul-template:alpine
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - name: company-config
              mountPath: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/companyRootCA.crt
              subPath: companyRootCA.crt
            - name: vault-consul-config
              mountPath: /etc/consul-template/consul_template_config.hcl
              subPath: consul_template_config.hcl
            - name: vault-token
              mountPath: /home/vault
            - name: vault-consul-config
              mountPath: /etc/templates/config.tmpl
              subPath: config.tmpl
            - name: shared-data
              mountPath: /etc/secrets
          env:
            - name: HOME
              value: /home/vault
            - name: VAULT_ADDR
              value: "{{ .Values.vault.endpoint }}"
            - name: VAULT_NAMESPACE
              value: "company/devops/tarchon/{{ .Values.environmentName }}"
          args:
            [
              "-config=/etc/consul-template/consul_template_config.hcl",
              "-log-level=trace",
            ]
        - name: "{{ .Values.web.service.name }}"
          image: "{{ .Values.image.registry }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: "{{ .Values.image.imagePullPolicy }}"
          args: [
            "bash", 
            "-c", 
            "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 ecops_cross_team_platform_backend.wsgi:application"
          ]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-data
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/config.json
              subPath: config.json
          {{- if $.Values.environmentVariables }}
          env:
            {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.environmentVariables }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: "{{ $.Release.Name }}-config"
                  key: {{ $key | quote }}
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.web.service.port }}
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

`consul-template` generates a file `/etc/secrets/config.json` with credentials that come from HashiCorp Vault in the shared volume `shared-data`.

In my application container I bind the file in a different directory (`/usr/src/app/config.json`) (because the application wants the file to be in different directory compared to where `consul-template` generates the file).

The problem is that whenever the file `config.json` is updated in the volume that is mounted in the `consul-template` container, the modification is not propagated to the other containers, so I end up having the application container with stale non-working data.

At the beginning, I initially thought it was a problem caused by the `readOnly` volumeMount option, however the problem was still present after removing it.

Comment: Can you exec into your pod and verify whether `/etc/secrets/config.json` is generated and logs too if there are other issues. One more suggestion (don't know if it may work), try removing subPath from other container and just give `/usr/src/app`.

Comment: Yes, the `/etc/secrets/config.json` file is properly generated in both containers upon pod creation. The problem is that after 24 hours (because Vault credential TTL is 24hours), `consul-template` generates a new credential in the `/etc/secrets/config.json` file and it should be propagated to the other containers, but because of this the application breaks because it uses stale non-working database credentials.

Comment: I attempted removing the subPath but it overridden the entire `/usr/src/app` folder,  breaking the entire application.

Comment: Yes it will override, that's the expected behavior. But wanted to check if it is updating the file. It should work if you have only file in that folder. If there's a way you can change the config path then you can try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As anmol said in the comments, it was indeed the fact of binding a single file using `subPath` in the directory.

The solution was to remove the subPath and bind the `shared-data` volume into a single-scoped folder (ie. `/usr/src/app/credentials`) so that it won't go wrong with other things.

**Solution:**

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: shared-data
    mountPath: /usr/src/app/credentials
```

**Instead of:**

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: shared-data
    mountPath: /usr/src/app/config.json
    subPath: config.json
```